# MapReduce algorithm for simple internet graph example

Tags: mapreduce, graph-theory

Let G be the internet graph. The input to the first MapReduce round are tuples of the
form (siteA,siteB) if there is a link on siteA to siteB. How can I print all pairs of webpages that have a common successor (together with the name of the successor page) by using the MapReduce paradigm?

I tried in the first Map round to emit (siteB, siteA) tuples but I'm not sure how and when to construct the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

- LOOP V over vertices

  - LOOP A over parents of V

    - LOOP B over parents of V

      - IF A != B

        - OUTPUT A,B since they have a common child ( V )

Comment: I am interested in answers that use Map-Reduce functions

Comment: So?  Implement the algorithm with your library's methods.  If none are suitable, then you have the wrong library for this.  Any competent graph theory library will have such methods

Comment: It was more of a 'doing by hand' exercise, not any code needed